# C++ Reading multiple lines from a file to a single string

Tags: c++, string, file, file-io

I have an input file of dna.txt which looks like what is below. I'm trying to read all of the characters to a single string and I'm not allowed to use a character array. How would I go about doing this.

```
cggccgattgtattctgtatagaaaaacac
atacagatggattttaactagagc
aagtcgcaataaccagcgagtattaca
cctcgaccaaatcctcgaattctc
```

Comment: You would read them into a std::string, probably using std::getline.

Comment: Use `std::istreambuf_iterator` and the `std::string`'s two argument template constructor, to do this one statement.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
std::string dna;
std::string text_read;
while (getline(input_file, text_read))
{
    dna += text_read;
}
```

In the above loop, each line is read into a separate variable.
After the line is read, then it is appended to the DNA string.

**Edit 1: Example working program:**
*Note: on some platforms, there may be a `\r'` in the buffer which causes portions to be overwritten when displayed.*

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream input_file("./data.txt");
    std::string dna;
    std::string text_read;
    while (std::getline(input_file, text_read))
    {
        const std::string::size_type position = text_read.find('\r');
        if (position != std::string::npos)
        {
            text_read.erase(position);
        }
        dna += text_read;
    }
    std::cout << "As one long string:\n"
              << dna;
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
$ ./dna.exe
As one long string:
cggccgattgtattctgtatagaaaaacacatacagatggattttaactagagcaagtcgcaataaccagcgagtattacacctcgaccaaatcctcgaattctc
```

The file "data.txt":

```
cggccgattgtattctgtatagaaaaacac
atacagatggattttaactagagc
aagtcgcaataaccagcgagtattaca
cctcgaccaaatcctcgaattctc
```

The program compiled using `g++` version 5.3.0 on Cygwin terminal.

The issue was found by using the `gdb` debugger.

Comment: @BrycePurnell See my latest edit.  You could catch the issue by using a debugger.  It's a platform issue, some use line ending of `\n` only while others use both `\r` and `\n`.  The `std::getline` only removes `\n`, not `\r`.